# Behaviour of website developed using jQuery mobile in mobiles and Tablets

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

For example if I am developing an web application for iPhone, Blackberry mobiles. I will try to design content as per the device screen. If I open the same website in Tablets, screen size will be different and content will be expanded to screen width because it is liquid layout. This is what I am wondering. If I design a button using jQuery mobile, it will occupy the total width of the screen(Although we can change, this is not my case). But in tablet PC it will be expanded to total width of the screen, it does not look good. Is not it? So, here my question is What are things does jQuery mobile developer should take care of. And Is it necessary to develop website for different screen resolutions...?

Comment: You're referring to a `responsive design` wherein the layout changes based on what orientation / screen size the user is looking at. There' many documented methods out there. jQuery mobile aims at making this as smooth as possible. It doesn't look `weird` per se, but it also doesn't look perfect. If you'd prefer to make your content a bit cleaner, and more `web-like` for tablets; just google [responsive web design](http://tinyurl.com/33nqvdr)

Comment: @OhgodwhyThanks for the Response..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Jquery mobile latest version.It supports the responsive web designs.
There are certain specifications for header,content,footer of the web pages in jquery mobile.
Go along with that.Also the grid layout displays the web page neatly in cross devices.
Developers need to customize the desired design accordingly with jquery mobile css.